# Swift and Storyboard, failed to set contentViewController

Tags: swift, macos-mojave

Some users of [RsyncOSX](https://github.com/rsyncOSX/RsyncOSX/issues/1949) has experienced an issue on Mojave (10.14.6) with the following error:

Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): must provide an environment dictionary

RsyncOSX is a Swift and Storyboard based macOS app, and I am not able to reproduce the error. It is not a compiler issue, and I dont have any idea what causes the issue. The initial viewcontroller is set in Storyboard, there is no such issue on either 10.15 or 11.00 (Big Sur)..

Comment: Looks like the devs are active on that issue, why don't you ask them?

Comment: The issue is closed, problem is not related to the storyboard..